# is it possible to get faster single-threaded compute out of aws aurora postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, single-threaded

I'm looking for a way to get better single-threaded performance for postgresql, preferably with aurora postgresql

my application connects to a postgresql database.
i really need to improve performance.
all our tests tend to show that the bottleneck is cpu (processing), single-threaded performance.
that is to say:
- adding more cores helps not at all
- moving to a machine with fewer cores, and higher frequencies helps significantly

currently we have been using high-frequency cpu dedicated servers, but for obvious reasons, would like to move to a managed db, such as aurora postgresql.

the problem is, the underlying hardware seems to be much slower thread by thread than what we currently have.

there is an option to make your cores run fewer threads, but only for oracle.

does anybody know of a configuration or managed db where i can get high single thread performance for postgresql ?

many thanks

Comment: You'll probably get much more benefit by rethinking your high-CPU queries. Clock rate represents a hard limit on how much you can improve single-thread performance.

Comment: Postgres supports multi-threaded query execution. Did you try to enable that? Maybe JIT compilation introduced in Postgres 10 might also help you there

Comment: I can't accept a_horse_with_no_name 's answer because it's a comment, but we're currently testing parallel queries in postgresql 11 and the results are excellent. we had hit a wall with a 5.0 db master, and for some queries our time is halved, for some it's even faster.